# Can I call a user-defined function in JPQL using Oracle and Apache OpenJPA?

Tags: user-defined-functions, jpql, openjpa

I'm using Apache OpenJPA and I need to call a user-defined function, but when I try, I'm getting this error:

> "Se ha encontrado "MY_FUNCTION (" en el carácter 127, pero se
>   esperaba: ["(", "*", "+", "-", ".", "/", ":", "<", "<=", "<>", "=",
>   ">", ">=", "?", "ABS", "ALL", "AND", "ANY", "AS", "ASC", "AVG",
>   "BETWEEN", "BOTH", "BY", "CONCAT", "COUNT", "CURRENT_DATE",
>   "CURRENT_TIME", "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP", "DELETE", "DESC", "DISTINCT",
>   "EMPTY", "ESCAPE", "EXISTS", "FETCH", "FROM", "GROUP", "HAVING", "IN",
>   "INDEX", "INNER", "IS", "JOIN", "KEY", "LEADING", "LEFT", "LENGTH",
>   "LIKE", "LOCATE", "LOWER", "MAX", "MEMBER", "MIN", "MOD", "NEW",
>   "NOT", "NULL", "OBJECT", "OF", "OR", "ORDER", "OUTER", "SELECT",
>   "SET", "SIZE", "SOME", "SQRT", "SUBSTRING", "SUM", "TRAILING", "TRIM",
>   "TYPE", "UPDATE", "UPPER", "VALUE", "WHERE", , , , , , , , , ]." al
>   analizar JPQL "SELECT COUNT(r.regionId) FROM Region r INNER JOIN
>   r.systemUserGroups sug WHERE sug.systemUserGroupId =
>   :systemUserGroupId AND MY_FUNCTION() > 0". Consulte el seguimiento de
>   la pila anidado para obtener el error de análisis inicial.

I have seen is possible when you are using Hibernate. You need to register the function inheriting from the Dialect class.
If you are using EclipseLink, you can use the FUNCTION or FUNC function to call another function.
But I've not found how to call a user-defined function using Apache OpenJPA.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to call a stored Procedure? via PL/SQL?

Comment: I'm using native queries now. Thanks for your interest.